# Lower system volume

Tags: android

I want to lower the ringtone, media volume, and alarm volume from an app (button press, no slider). So I've been reading up on [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) , but I'm still a bit confused on how to do this.

Also, with Audio Manager, is the volume set for the whole phone or just for the app? I want it to be for the whole phone

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd post a few snippets of the code that you came up with. Also add a description what doesn't work for you or what exactly you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I'm still a bit confused on how to do this

Call `adjustStreamVolume()` with your desired stream (e.g., `STREAM_ALARM`) and change (e.g., `-1`). [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Volume) that demonstrates this.

> is the volume set for the whole phone or just for the app?

Android does not have a concept of app-specific volume, so this is for the whole phone.